# How to add a form class as a library class in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

Most of my Form classes are not part of the library but some are. Those that are part of class library have the members that I need to use in the Form classes. How do I make it so Class is part of the Class library? Or Don't I even have to switch the form class to library class to access a `Junction_ID` member? or how do I even add the `Junction_ID` member to my form class without switching it to the library class? For example in below picture I want to use that `Junction_ID` as a member of `Form_supfrm_CenteneTexas_Interview`. I haven't ever dealt with this before so please help!

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access each control of an opened form from anywhere in your project. [[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195841%28v=office.15%29.aspx]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195841%28v=office.15%29.aspx%5d)